# If else assignment "move out of borrowed content"

Tags: if-statement, rust, binary-search-tree, variable-assignment

This is a snippet of Rust code which performs an insertion on a common binary search tree. I want the reference to the branch on which I'll perform the insertion.

```
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn insert(&mut self, elem: i32) {
        let ref mut a = if elem < self.value {
            self.left
        } else {
            self.right
        };

        // ...
    }
}
```

This code is invalid. After tweaking it, I came to understand when I perform a if/else statement, Rust moves the content before assigning it. This solution works, but it's really ugly...

```
let a = if elem < self.value {
    let ref mut b = self.left;
    b
} else {
    let ref mut b = self.right;
    b
};
```

Is there a way to handle the thing without recurring to a Box? I could use a pointer, but it really looks like overkill.

*After commenting, this is the entire code*

```
fn insert(&mut self, elem: i32) {
    let target = if elem < self.value {
        &mut self.left
    } else {
        &mut self.right
    };

    match target.as_mut() {
        None => {}
        Some(ref mut node) => {
            node.insert(elem);
            return;
        }
    }

    mem::replace(&mut *target, Some(Box::new(Node::new(elem))));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `ref` keyword. See this playground link that works without it: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9b072fcef00aa9ac73ee6e2273df7d03&version=stable . I assign `a` to be a mutable reference to either `self.left` or `self.right`

Comment: TBH as a beginner I find bindings with `ref` to be confusing and only would use it in a pattern-matching context (`match` or `if let`) where I can't get the code to compile without it.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I think I was just getting confused because after I'm using actually a match... at this point I show the insert code...

Comment: As you see, later I do some match etc. I guess I started using ref because the 1st versions didn't work... I smashed my head against the borrow checker so many times I became numb.

Comment: Is that last edit an *answer*? If so, it doesn't belong in the *question*. You are welcome to put your own answer below, instead.

Comment: No, it's not an answer. The answer was provided by @turbulencetoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, in your original attempt the "then" and "else" branches both attempt to **move** the left or right box out of your `&mut self` borrowed content, and this is not allowed.

```
let ref mut a = if elem < self.value {
    self.left
} else {
    self.right
};
```

Your second attempt compiles but is ugly, as you said. This code avoids moving out of the borrowed content by referring to the left and right box by `ref mut` mutable reference.

```
let a = if elem < self.value {
    let ref mut b = self.left;
    b
} else {
    let ref mut b = self.right;
    b
};
```

A cleaner way to refer to something by mutable reference is with the `&mut` operator. The if-statement should be:

```
let a = if elem < self.value {
    &mut self.left
} else {
    &mut self.right
};
```